# Error in installing intel graphics driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, intel, drivers

Please read through what I have tried. I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bit i386 installed on my IBM-T43 laptop.

My processor is Intel® Pentium(R) M processor 1.73GHz and graphics is Intel® 915GM x86/MMX/SSE2.

After downloading I was able to ./configure correctly without errors. When I try make I get the following error

```
Making all in uxa
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/arhaz/Downloads/xf86-video-intel-2.99.917/src/uxa'
  CC       intel_driver.lo
intel_driver.c: In function 'redisplay_dirty':
intel_driver.c:645:2: error: too many arguments to function 'PixmapSyncDirtyHelper'
  PixmapSyncDirtyHelper(dirty, &pixregion);
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/xorg/gc.h:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/dix.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/privates.h:151,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/cursor.h:53,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/scrnintstr.h:53,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/xf86str.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/xf86.h:44,
                 from intel_driver.c:49:
/usr/include/xorg/pixmap.h:131:1: note: declared here
 PixmapSyncDirtyHelper(PixmapDirtyUpdatePtr dirty);
 ^
Makefile:524: recipe for target 'intel_driver.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [intel_driver.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/arhaz/Downloads/xf86-video-intel-2.99.917/src/uxa'
Makefile:598: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/arhaz/Downloads/xf86-video-intel-2.99.917/src'
Makefile:468: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/arhaz/Downloads/xf86-video-intel-2.99.917'
Makefile:399: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What can I do to resolve the issue and install the drivers?
Am I looking at a dated driver? If yes, where can I find the latest intel drivers for my machine running ubuntu?

Thanks for your time.

I was actually using a dated driver. The latest ones can be found here (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads). I tried with the 2016Q1 Intel Graphics Stack Release however I get the exact same error above on make. Seems like issues are not being resolved at Intel.

This is the output from ./configure. May help in resolving issue

`xf86-video-intel 2.99.917 will be compiled with:
  Xorg Video ABI version: 20.0
  Acceleration backends: none *sna uxa
  Additional debugging support? none
  Support for Kernel Mode Setting? yes
  Support for legacy User Mode Setting (for i810)? yes
  Support for Direct Rendering Infrastructure: DRI1 DRI2 Present
  Support for Xv motion compensation (XvMC and libXvMC): no
  Build additional tools and utilities? xf86-video-intel-backlight-helper`

Update - I do not know how to attach image to comment so updating the post ;-)
[xrandr output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t2w4.png)

Comment: Intel merges their stuff into the mainline open-source repositories, so that graphics stack is just a different version of the same one that Ubuntu already ships.  Is there some reason you want to install drivers from 2014 on Ubuntu 2016.04?  Did the newer version shipped by Ubuntu break something for hardware as old as Pentium-M / i915?

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes,

It did not break anything however the video display resolution is very low. I cannot go beyond 1024 X 768. I want to have better resolution.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the native screen resolution of your T43?  A quick google says that [some T43 models have 1024x768 screens](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/documents/pd012235).  Look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to make sure the Intel drivers are being used, and not a fallback like VESA or something.

Comment: Hi @Peter Cordes 

It is using intel drivers. Here is the partial output

 45.947] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1024x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    45.947] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 270 x 203 -- this may be a problem

I had windows xp on it and it had intel drivers with better display at the same resolution. 

Why is my screen size being set so small 270 x 203

Comment: That's the physical size in millimetres.

Comment: But the display is like running windows in recovery mode.

Comment: Run `xrandr` to show available modes, with the current one selected.  That should confirm that the pixel resolution is really 1024x768.  (Or use your desktop GUI's screen config tool).

Comment: @PeterCordes added xrandr output image to original post

Comment: Screengrab of my display setting [2]  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iDLSd.png

Comment: xrandr's output is text; why did you post an image of it?  Anyway, your drivers are working fine, and both images confirm that your screen is running at its max/native resolution of 1024x768.  That's pretty small, but it's all that your old laptop supports.

Comment: I did not wish leave out anything important from the xrandr's output therefore the image. Well that is all ubuntu has to offer then. Thanks for all your help

Comment: That's all **your hardware** has to offer.  It's not an Ubuntu limitation; there's just no point in running a virtual resolution higher than the physical resolution of your screen.  Use an external monitor if you want higher rez.

Comment: And a code-formatting block would have exactly represented the xrandr output.  No need for an image.